# Enter string into array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to enter these strings into a 2 dimensional array but I am unsure of how to parse the strings. How do I take each individual string and enter it into the array.

```
static String[] initStrings =
{
     "...../...\\",
     "..\\.......",
     "......./..",
     "..........",
     "........\\.",
     "..........",
     "..........",
     ".....\\../.",
     "..\\....../",
     ".........."
};

static void initialize() {
    NumRows = initStrings.length;
    NumCol = initStrings.length;
    squares = new int[NumRows] [NumCol];
}

}
}
```

Comment: [I knew that this array looked familiar...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26538139/1079354)

Answer (score 1):

This is the format for 2D arrays:

```
static String[][] initStrings =
    {
     {"...../...\\"},
     {"..\\......."},
     {"......./.."},
     {".........."},
     {"........\\."},
     {".........."},
     {".........."},
     {".....\\../."},
     {"..\\....../"},
     {".........."}
    };
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert String[] to String

Comment: Did you use double [], i.e. [][]?

Answer (score 0):

You better try this one:-

```
static String array[][]={{"...../...\\","..\\.......","......./..","...........","........\\.",},{"..........","..........",".....\\../.","..\\....../",".........."}};
```

Give it a try.
And,if you want to display the elements,use this snippet:-

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
System.out.print(array[i][j]);
}
System.out.println();
}
```